# How To Host a Dynamic website Developed in Eclipse

Tags: jsp, hosting, servlets

i developed a small dynamic website in my Eclipse

i want to Host in Internet
I have domain and Hosting

How can i host this Dynamic website?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a website using jsp and you are using a Tomcat server (as i guess by your tags) You  can just create a .war file, than Tomcat will deploy it by himself. Go to File-->export-->WAR file, it will create a .war file that you can load on your space. Note that to make a war file you need to have web.xml file in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: How to load .war file in my webhost? am i need to upload using FTP?

Comment: well if your hosting service doesn't give you a graphic interface for upload files you need to use ftp... Try the mozilla plugin fireFTP. You just insert the name of the site, username and password in "create account" and than you can manage data on server as normal folders